# Pivot table field with multiple field VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to do select the years between a range for a pivot table filter. For example: 1980 to 1990. The range will be given by the user input as startyear and endyear. I tried using for loop for it and it takes too long. It also only selects the year 1989 and 1990.
This is the code:

```
For x = startyear To endyear
     For Each pvtItem In pvt.PivotFields("Build Year").PivotItems
           If pvtItem.Name = startyear Then
            
               On Error Resume Next
              pvtItem.Visible = True
                
         Else
              On Error Resume Next
              pvtItem.Visible = False
                
         End If
       Next pvtItem
 startyear = startyear + 1
Next x
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check your data type, pvtItem.Name will return string so you need to make both data type same. Either string or integer.

Comment: I realised I have to use an array with the range of years included and then filter it. Without the array, only the startyear and endyear in the last loop will be included